# unable to mktemp: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: linux, unix, mktemp

I am unable to create a temp file using mktemp.
`mktemp /tmp/abc.XXXX`
Output obtained: 
    `mktemp: cannot create temp file /tmp/abc.D30575: Value too large for defined data type`
What could be the issue? Please guide.

Comment: what gives you `ls -al /tmp`?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type

Comment: @hek2mgl - File is not created in /tmp

Comment: @KD which version of mktemp are you using?

Comment: @hek2mgl  mktemp (GNU coreutils) 8.22